# ASP.NET if controller returns NotFound, try other route match or other controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, routes

I have 2 routes mapping that can handle the same route, however one is dynamic from CMS and other uses different controller, something like

```cs
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "Dynamic",
    pattern: "/{urlPath:regex(urlA|urlB)}/{slug}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Controller1", action = "Index" });

 app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "NonDynamic",
    pattern: "/{slug}/{*path}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Controller2", action = "Index" });
```

How can I try Controller2 or `NonDynamic` if `Dynamic` -> Controller1 returns 404.
Problem is that I don't know if Controller1 can handle it until I try to handle it and check if CMS has that page, but if not, I want to handle it with completely different controller2
`RedirectTo` is not an option - I don't want to have 301 or 302 redirects.
It does also seems to be not possible to use Action from different controller in another controller and keep context.

I could copy all the logic from Controller2 to Controller1, and just use different action based on cms response, but this is a mess and I don't want to mix those 2 controllers.

Is there a way to return from controller and tell the app to keep looking for another route match ?

Comment: Check the [Conventional routing order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-8.0#conventional-routing-order) and [URL matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-8.0#url-matching).The list of endpoints is prioritized according to the Endpoint.Order and the route template precedence, the EndpointSelector will chooses the highest priority endpoint from the matches as the best match, if it not found the endpoint from the Dynamic endpoint list, it will try to find endpoint from NonDynamic endpoint list

Comment: I think you missed the point -  I don't want to have some big list of supported paths etc, I could have constrain to look for them then, but  problem is that I have 2 controllers that can potentially deal with the same path.  I have kind of sorted it out, but it seems like a work around, I am calling Controller2 action from Controller1, it seems hacky but it works

Comment: I thought you want to use the nondynamic route, if the dynamic route can't handle the incoming request. Be default, asp.net core routing will do that according to the routing order and URL matching. If the incoming request does not match the nondynamic route, it will find the endpoint via the dynamic route. But it seems like you want to judge for yourself, if that is the case, you can create a custom middleware, then get the request url and check if CMS has this page, and then based on the result to change the Context.Request.RouteValue controller and action to use the dynamic route.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a middleware that you can notify on the way down the pipeline by setting a magic `HttpContext.Item`. When it detects this, it finds the endpoint you want to execute and sends it back up the middleware pipeline. This is going to break in all kinds of ways, but it seems to work for the specific case in your question.

```cs
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext, EndpointDataSource endpointDataSource)
{
    //on the way up, just proceed
    await next(httpContext);

    //on the way down, see if we got handed a route name to execute
    if (httpContext.Items["ReexecuteRouteName"] is string routeName)
    {
        httpContext.Items.Remove("ReexecuteRouteName");

        //find the endpoint by the given route name
        var endpoint = endpointDataSource.Endpoints.FirstOrDefault(e =>
            e.Metadata.GetMetadata<RouteNameMetadata>()?.RouteName == routeName);

        if (endpoint is null)
            return;

        //clear previously parsed route values
        var routeValues = httpContext.GetRouteData().Values;
        routeValues.Clear();

        //populate with new ones according to the new endpoint
        var route = endpoint.Metadata.GetMetadata<IRouteDiagnosticsMetadata>();
        var routeTemplate = TemplateParser.Parse(route?.Route);
        var templateMatcher = new TemplateMatcher(routeTemplate, new());
        templateMatcher.TryMatch(httpContext.Request.Path, routeValues);

        //set the endpoint
        httpContext.SetEndpoint(endpoint);

        //go back up the middleware pipeline
        await next(httpContext);
    }
}
```

In Controller1:

```cs
public IActionResult Index(string urlPath, string slug)
{
    var myPage = await db.QueryFirstOrDefaulf<PageStuff>(sql, new { slug });

    if (myPage is null) 
    {
        HttpContext.Items.Add("ReexecuteRouteName", "NonDynamic");
        //make sure not to start the response here
        return new NotFoundResult();
    }

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach, I will give it a go. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to fiddle with custom routing etc. why not have a single controller that handles both cases using an (injected) [Chain of Responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern)?

At the controller level, you might have something like this (I haven't checked if this compiles, so there may be typos):

```
public class MyController
{
    private readonly IMyService myService;

    public MyController(IMyService myService)
    {
        this.myService = myService;
    }

    public IActionResult Index(string urlPath, string slug)
    {
        return myService.Handle(urlPath, slug);
    }
}
```

You'll then have (at least) two implementation of the `IMyService` interface. The first one queries your CMS system:

```
public class CmsService : IMyService
{
    private readonly IMyService next;

    public CmsService(IMyService next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public IActionResult Handle(string urlPath, string slug)
    {        
        var result = // Look up the page in CMS
        if (result is null) // or however else you check existence
            return next.Handle(urlPath, slug);
        else
            return new OkResult(result);
    }
}
```

The second implementation of `IMyService` contains your fallback behaviour:

```
public class DefaultService : IMyService
{
    public IActionResult Handle(string urlPath, string slug)
    {
        // Implement default behaviour here...
    }
}
```

Finally, you wire up the (small) `IMyService` Chain of Responsibility like this:

```
new CmsService(new DefaultService())
```

It may be [more complex, but it's less complicated](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Simple-Made-Easy/) because you won't be [mucking around with exotic framework features](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2023/10/02/dependency-whac-a-mole), but rather taking advantage of well-understood design patterns.